# Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Model\Item does not extend \Magento\Framework\DataObject

Tags: magento2

I ma trying to render data from database to a custom block, but i am getting error as the below screenshot 
I've review the code multiple times and still con not catch the issue 
I am using Magento ver. 2.4.4

[image]

the code as the following snapshot 
**Model file => src/app/code/Mastering/SampleModule/Model/Item.php**

```
<?php 

namespace Mastering\SampleModel\Model;
use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;

class Item extends AbstractModel{
    protected function _construct(){
        $this->_init(\Mastering\SampleModule\Model\ResourceModel\Item::class);
    }
}
```

**ResourceModel file => src/app/code/Mastering/SampleModule/Model/ResourceModel/Item.php**

```
<?php 

namespace Mastering\SampleModule\Model\ResourceModel;
use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb;

class Item extends AbstractDb{
    
    public function _construct(){
        $this->_init('mastering_sample_item', 'id');
    }
    
}
```

**Collection file => src/app/code/Mastering/SampleModule/Model/ResourceModel/Item/Collection.php**

```
<?php

namespace Mastering\SampleModule\Model\ResourceModel\Item;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;


class Collection extends AbstractCollection{
    protected $_idFieldName = 'id';

    public function _construct(){
        $this->_init(
            \Mastering\SampleModule\Model\Item::class,
            \Mastering\SampleModule\Model\ResourceModel\Item::class
        );
    }
}
```

**Block file => src/app/code/Mastering/SampleModule/Block/Article.php**

```
<?php

namespace Mastering\SampleModule\Block;

use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Mastering\SampleModule\Model\ResourceModel\Item\Collection;
class Article extends Template
{
    /**
     * @var Collection
     */
    private $collection;

    /**
     * Display constructor.
     * @param Template\Context $context
     * @param Collection $collection
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,
        Collection $collection,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->collection = $collection;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection
     */
    public function getItems()
    {
        return $this->collection;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`src/app/code/Mastering/SampleModule/Model/Item.php`

Incorrect

```php
namespace Mastering\SampleModel\Model;
```

Correct

```php
namespace Mastering\SampleModule\Model;
```

Also I recommend to add following into your `etc/di.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Mastering\SampleModule\Model\Item">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="resource" xsi:type="object">Mastering\SampleModule\Model\ResourceModel\Item</argument>
            <argument name="resourceCollection" xsi:type="object">Mastering\SampleModule\Model\ResourceModel\Item\Collection</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```